# How can I extract Cyrillic alphabet or Latin characters from a string in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

If I have a string like 'Picá' in Redshift, how can I extract just the 'á'?

Trying to get at the count of foreign characters in a column full of strings.

Comment: Can you be more specific, how do you define a foreign characters? foreign to what?

Comment: Mostly anything outside of [A-Z],[a-z],[0-9] and punctuations. To be more specific, if you look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters. it's anything in the Latin or Cyrillic alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a count of non-ascii characters you could use something like

```
select regexp_count('Picá', '[^\u0000-\u007F]');
```

which returns the value 1.

If you really want a count of Latin or Cyrillic alphabet then you must probably revert to a redshift UDF.